# How to mount a .bin file on a Mac?

Tags: macos

I have a bin file and I want to mount it without having to burn it in my mac like my iso-files. How do I do that?

Comment: Daemon Tools works well.

Comment: Just tried in El Capitan: Open Disk Utility, File->Open and select the image file. .img extension works, haven't tried if it takes .bin.

Comment: Neither Daemon Tools nor Disk Utility will open a .bin file in Sierra.

Comment: I've used AnyToISO mac app to convert bin/cue files to iso. `bchunk` didn't work for me as I understand it's for converting audio files, but I wanted to convert Warcraft2 game image

Answer (score 25):

You can use the [bchunk](http://he.fi/bchunk/), which should be in MacPorts (alternatives are: **bin2iso** and **isodump**), to convert that .bin/.cue pair to .iso, and then mount ISO file. With bchunk, the command (run in console) would be

`bchunk image.bin image.cue image.iso`

There's also **ccd2iso**, but I believe it doesn't support .bin files - only .img.

Further, I'll be talking from a Linux perspective, but as long as Mac is a FreeBSD derivative, it may work. You may want to use the console **mount** command (run **man mount** to read the manual) together with **cdfs** or [cdemu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cdemu/). These will require lots of manuals reading and console love, and success will depend on what kind of kernel Macs use. Only try this as a last, really-desperate method.

Comment: with homebrew you can install bchunk with `brew install bchunk`

Comment: use `bchunk -w image.bin image.cue track` to output to wav files

Answer (score 6):

If you have Toast, add the bin file in Toast and save as image .toast file. Rename .toast extension to .dmg. Double-click to mount on desktop and copy content to hard drive.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> on the `.bin` file then select **Open With -> Disc Utility**.

Comment: This does not work for me on Mac OS X 10.9.

Answer (score 1):

`cabextract` is a package that provides utilities for using `.bin` files.  It's available [through MacPorts](http://macports.org).  It allows you to extract files from Microsoft cabinet files.

Answer (score -1):

A similar SuperUser question was asked here: [How to open .bin files in Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/144653/how-to-open-bin-files-in-mac)

The answer that worked for me for the particular **.bin** file I had downloaded was to simply rename it to end with ".iso" and then to mount it via the normal **.iso** mounting mechanisms available on macOS. In my instance (on macOS Mojave), I right clicked on the newly renamed **.iso** file and selected **Open With -> DiskImageMounter (default)**